# Is there a ZODB Storage class implementation that runs entirely in memory?

Tags: storage, backend, in-memory, zodb

ZODB lets users swap storage backends through the `Storage` class. Some implementations included with the package includes `FileStorage` (store your data in a big file) and `ClientStorage` (store all your data over the network onto a ZODB/ZEO server-of-sorts).

In order to test-drive my development against ZODB I would like to run my tests with an in-memory ZODB: is there a `InMemoryStorage` or some such?

I found [this thread](http://www.mail-archive.com/zodb-dev@zope.org/msg01958.html) alluding to some successful implementation of `FileStorage` based on StringIO but I'm afraid my Python-foo mightn't be good enough to quickly hack up a reliable backend.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it was [in the docs all along](http://zodb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#in-memory-for-testing). They're called `DemoStorage` and `MappedStorage`.

I couldn't find it at first because its Google rankings were so low!

I post this for posterity...

Comment: I was looking for this and couldn't find, too. `FileStorage` with no parameters will create an in-memory storage but it's not effective for testing. Thanks!